# Date range filter in ng-table angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bootstrap-daterangepicker

I am using angularjs ng-tables for displaying data through django view and trying to add bootstrap date range filter in ng-table but it is showing the following error:-

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider:
>   dateRangeFilterFilterProvider <- dateRangeFilterFilter

I want to add the date range filter so that I can search the data according to that. The filter is visible but getting the above error and filtering is not happening. I am stuck and not getting where I am doing wrong. It would be great if someone can help me with this.

**app.js**

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    var myapp = angular
        .module('app.tables')
        .controller('NGTableCtrl', NGTableCtrl);

function parseDate(input) {
              return Date.parse(input); 
            }

           myapp.filter("dateRangeFilter", function() {
            return function(items, from, to) {
                  var df = parseDate(from);
                  var dt = parseDate(to);
                  var result = [];        
                  for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++){
                      var date_bet = items[i].datetime;
                      if (date_bet > df && dt > date_bet)  {
                          result.push(items[i]);
                      }
                  }
                  return result;
            };
          });

    NGTableCtrl.$inject = ['$filter', '$http', 'ngTableParams', '$resource', '$timeout', 'ngTableDataService'];
    function NGTableCtrl($filter, $http, ngTableParams, $resource, $timeout, ngTableDataService) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.title = 'Controller';

        activate();





        function activate() {
          vm.today = function() {
                vm.dt2 = new Date(2015,11,26);
                vm.dt1 = new Date(2015,11,17);

              };    

              vm.today();
              vm.toggleMin = function() {
                vm.minDate = vm.minDate ? null : new Date();
              };
              vm.toggleMin();
              vm.maxDate = new Date(2020, 5, 22);

              vm.open1 = function($event) {
                vm.status1.opened = true;
              };

              vm.open2 = function($event) {
                vm.status2.opened = true;
              };

              vm.setDate = function(year, month, day) {
                vm.dt1 = new Date(year, month, day);
                vm.dt2 = new Date(year, month, day);

              };

              vm.dateOptions = {
                formatYear: 'yy',
                startingDay: 1
              };

              vm.formats = ['dd-MMMM-yyyy', 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'dd.MM.yyyy', 'shortDate'];
              vm.format = vm.formats[0];

              vm.status1 = {
                opened: false
              };

              vm.status2 = {
                opened: false
              };
                  var tableData = [];
                  var ratingData = [];

                vm.tableParams5 = new ngTableParams({
                page: 1,
                count: 10,
                sorting: {
                    image_url: 'asc',
                    title: 'asc',
                    seller_name: 'asc',
                    price: 'asc',
                    product_rating: 'asc',
                    vendor_rating: 'asc'     
                },
                 filter: {
                    image_url: '',
                    title: '',
                    seller_name: '',
                    price: '',
                    product_rating: '',
                    vendor_rating: ''

                }
            },{
                total:tableData.length,

                getData : function($defer,params){
                  ngTableDataService.getData( $defer, params);
                    $http.get('/reviews/').then(function(response) {
                        tableData = response.data.product_whole_data;
                        console.log(tableData);

                        var filteredData = params.filter() ?
                         $filter('filter')(tableData, params.filter()) :
                         tableData;

                        var orderedData = params.sorting() ?
                          $filter('orderBy')(filteredData, params.orderBy()) :
                          filteredData;
                          params.total(orderedData.length);

                        $defer.resolve(orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));

                    });
                }


            });
```

**html**

```
<div class="panel panel-default">

      <h4>From Date</h4>
      <p class="input-group">
         <input type="text" uib-datepicker-popup="{{table.format}}" ng-model="table.dt1" is-open="table.status1.opened"  max-date="'table.maxDate'" datepicker-options="table.dateOptions" date-disabled="table.disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true"
         close-text="Close" class="form-control" />
         <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" ng-click="table.open1($event)" class="btn btn-default">
               <em class="fa fa-calendar"></em>
            </button>
         </span>
      </p>
      <h4>To Date</h4>
       <p class="input-group">
         <input type="text" uib-datepicker-popup="{{table.format}}" ng-model="table.dt2" is-open="table.status2.opened"  max-date="'table.maxDate'" datepicker-options="table.dateOptions" date-disabled="table.disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true"
         close-text="Close" class="form-control" />
         <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" ng-click="table.open2($event)" class="btn btn-default">
               <em class="fa fa-calendar"></em>
            </button>
         </span>
      </p>
      <table ng-table="table.tableParams5" class="table" show-filter="true">
         <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="product_whole_data in $data | dateRangeFilter:dt1:dt2">
               <td data-title="'Channel'" filter="{ 'channel_name': 'text' }" sortable="'channel_name'" class="text-center">{{product_whole_data.channel_name}}</td>
               <td data-title="'Image'" filter="{ 'image_url': 'text' }" sortable="'image_url'"><div class="media"><img src="{{product_whole_data.image_url}}" alt="Image" class="media-box-object img-responsive img-rounded thumb64"></div></td>
               <td data-title="'Product Name'" filter="{ 'title': 'text' }" sortable="'title'" class="text-center">{{product_whole_data.title}}</td>
               <td data-title="'Seller Name'" filter="{ 'seller_name': 'text' }" sortable="'seller_name'" class="text-center">{{product_whole_data.seller_name}}</td>
               <td data-title="'Price'" filter="{ 'price': 'text' }" sortable="'price'" class="text-center">{{product_whole_data.price}}</td>
               <td data-title="'Product Rating'" filter="{ 'product_rating': 'text' }" sortable="'product_rating'" class="text-center">{{product_whole_data.product_rating}}</td>
               <td data-title="'Vendor Rating'" filter="{ 'vendor_rating': 'text' }" sortable="'vendor_rating'" class="text-center">{{product_whole_data.vendor_rating}}</td>

            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </div>
```

Comment: why `myapp.filter`  inside the function?

Comment: because outside the function it is throwing this error ReferenceError: parseDate is not defined

Comment: use the `Date.parse` directly inside the filter ; not that function

Comment: okay. let me try that

Comment: @User0706 can i connect with you by email? anatoliy.ruchka at gmail.com

Comment: yeah sure atripathi@ediode.com

Answer (score 0):

Updated: Instead of creating a function to return the parsed date, just call Date.parse() directly

It's because you created your filter **inside** your controller.

```
   var myapp = angular
            .module('app.tables')
            .controller('NGTableCtrl', NGTableCtrl);

            // your filter should be here
            myapp.filter("dateRangeFilter", function() {
                return function(items, from, to) {
                  var df = Date.parse(from);
                  var dt = Date.parse(to);
              };
            });

        NGTableCtrl.$inject = ['$filter', '$http', 'ngTableParams', '$resource', '$timeout', 'ngTableDataService'];
        function NGTableCtrl($filter, $http, ngTableParams, $resource, $timeout, ngTableDataService) {
    // your existing code
    }
```

Comment: it is giving this error now after adding filter outside the function base.js:23068 ReferenceError: parseDate is not defined

Comment: @User0706 instead of using the parseDate function, just call Date.parse() directly. I updated my answer.

Comment: Also you can just remove the parseDate function from your controller since it's not useful anymore.

Comment: Okay. Let me try that

Comment: getting this error base.js:23068 TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: In what line is it occuring? When you do `tableData.length`? `orderedData.length`? or `items.length`? Also in your `ng-repeat`, you use `$data`. Where did you declare this variable?

Comment: items.length and in ng-repeat, using $data is displaying my data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115524/discussion-between-alex-andrea-and-user0706).